# Multiplicity of singular points in a curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to solve the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq P^{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible curve of degree $n\geq1$. Let $m_P (\mathcal C)$ be the multiplicity of $P$, prove that $$\sum_{P}m_{P}(\mathcal{C})(m_{P}(\mathcal{C})-1)\leq n(n-1)$$and prove that $\mathcal{C}$ has at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ singular points.

I think I can use this somehow, but maybe I am wrong:

> Let $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C'$ be two curves, then: $$\sum_{P}m_{P}(\mathcal{C})m_{P}(\mathcal{C}')\leq \mathrm{degree}(\mathcal C)\cdot \mathrm{degree}(\mathcal C ')$$

My intuition tells me that if $\mathcal C =\mathrm V (F)$, then maybe I can take  $\mathcal C'=\mathrm V (F')$, where $F'$ is some derivative of $F$, so the multiplicity of P in the new curve will be the multiplicity in $\mathcal C$ less one, and the degree of the new curve will be $n-1$.

How can I take that derivative? Would any partial derivative work here? Is it true that, for example $\mathcal C'=\mathrm V \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\right)$ verifies this?

Also, I don't know how to answer the second part.

Comment: Singular points of $\mathcal C = V(F)$ are the points where *all* the partial derivatives of $F$ vanish. Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin I was taught that as a definition. A singular point is a point where all partial derivatives are zero.

Comment: I'm just emphasizing that you know the answer to one of your questions, then. Setting one partial derivative equal to $0$ won't do it.

Comment: So $\mathcal C' = \mathrm V (F_X, F_Y, F_Z )$ would do it?

Comment: Yes. Note that you're certainly not dealing with a complete intersection here. For example, Euler's theorem says that $XF_X + YF_Y + ZF_Z = 0$.

Comment: But you have the right idea to think about $C'$ as you originally stated it. Certainly the singular points must be a subset of the intersection locus $C\cdot C'$.

Comment: I realized that $\mathrm V (F_X, F_Y, F_Z)$ is not a curve. It is the set of singular points of $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you should pick $\mathcal C'$ to be a [polar curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_curve) of $\mathcal C$. You cannot always choose $F_X$ as the defining equation because it might be zero, but some linear combination of the partial derivatives will work.

For the second part, note that $P$ is a singular point of $\mathcal C$ if and only if $m_P(\mathcal C)\ge 2$ and the number $k$ of singular points of $\mathcal C$ can therefore be estimated as
$$
k = \#\{P\mid m_P(\mathcal C)>1\} \le \tfrac12 \sum_P 2\cdot (m_P(\mathcal C)-1)\le  \tfrac12 \sum_{P} m_P(\mathcal C)\cdot(m_P(\mathcal C)-1)
\le \tfrac{n(n-1)}2.
$$

Comment: So if $P=(a:b:c)$, then I have to use that $\mathcal{C}'=\mathrm{V}(aF_{X}+bF_{Y}+cF_{Z})$? I don't see that the singular points of $\mathcal C$ are the same as the ones in $\mathcal C '$...

Comment: Also, I don't understand the $\frac{1}{2}$ before the sum in the second step.

Comment: The $1/2$ is there because $\frac 12\cdot 2 = 1$. (We're counting the points, hence summing over, $P$ with $m_P(\mathcal C)>1$.)

Comment: @mkspk: would you add your definition of multiplicity in the question? I can try to elaborate further from there.